# How to make torch cutting logo out of a plane (steel) and falling pieces.?

Tags: animation

I want to make a plane, which i can cut in shape of a logo and then the cutout piece will fall revealing the logo. I can make the torch but struggling with cutting a plane. Please help.

I wanna make animation similar to this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MTBQI2SiYGw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with a plane, you can use the knife tool <kbd>K</kbd> to cut a logo into it.

[image: simple logo mesh]

Then in face select mode select the faces you want to come out. Use <kbd>P</kbd>*->Selection* to break the selected faces into a new object that are located at the same position, so both objects will blend in as one. Note that a subsurf modifier will pull the edges apart and make the seam visible.

Now you animate the location of the piece you want to fall. Go to the frame you want it in place, say 20, and press <kbd>I</kbd>*->LocRot* to add a keyframe for the location and rotation. Move ahead a few frames and move the logo and add another keyframe. Repeat a few times to have it move and rotate as you want.

[image: simple animation]

For the effects you can combine that animation with [dynamic paint](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QIFC7NA0tSs) and [particles](https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/how-to-make-sparks?rq=sparks).

Comment: Wow thank you, could you also tell me how can i combine the dynamic paint with particles? Like an object is emitting particles, how can i add the d paint on it?

Comment: You can enable dynamic paint and particles on the same object, so as it emits particles it can also be the brush that paints the surface distortion.